'error: subprocess-exited-with-error' while installing my requirements/local.txt file after cloning the repo
Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      running dist_info
      creating C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-o75tij8k\psycopg_c.egg-info
      writing C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-o75tij8k\psycopg_c.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-o75tij8k\psycopg_c.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-o75tij8k\psycopg_c.egg-info\top_level.txt
      writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-o75tij8k\psycopg_c.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      couldn't run 'pg_config' --includedir: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
I'm encountering this error while installing requirements/local.txt after cloning repo, what could be the reason and a solution for this?
I was expecting all the dependencies to be installed but encountered this error

Try installing psycopg2-binary instead of psycopg2, which requires compilation.
